# 550 5.1.1 relay denied NDR Error

Tags: exchange-2007, ndr

I'm having problem with my email getting rejected like the following NDR, can anyone know or help me how to prevent this blockage please ?

```
From: Administrator 
Sent: Monday, 1 November 2010 3:35 PM
To: System Administrator
Subject: Undeliverable: Please reply to email
```

Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

enquiry@starrpartnersfairfield.com.au
The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.

The following organization rejected your message: mx2.bne.server-mail.com.

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: mail.domain.com

enquiry@starrpartnersfairfield.com.au
mx2.bne.server-mail.com #> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

Received: from Exch-01.domain.com (Exch-01.domain.com [10.2.2.4])   by
 mail.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6B8A527F      for
 ; Mon,  1 Nov 2010 15:34:23 +1100
 (EST)
Received: from Exch-01.domain.com ([10.2.2.4]) by Exch-01.domain.com
 ([10.2.2.4]) with mapi; Mon, 1 Nov 2010 15:34:56 +1100
From: System Administrator 
To: RECEPTION2FFLD 
Date: Mon, 1 Nov 2010 15:34:54 +1100
Subject: RE: Please reply to email
Thread-Topic: Please reply to email
Thread-Index: Act5e+v9lQKUx/7yTd6HPQBUxPs70AAAiJQQ
Message-ID: 
References: 
In-Reply-To: 
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
acceptlanguage: en-US
Content-Type: multipart/related;
        boundary="_007_BE6DB3905E87A7448CD6EE0AC22A4D862D1AED6E80Exch-01itreec_";
        type="multipart/alternative"
MIME-Version: 1.0

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the NDR you received: `The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system.`.

If you are sending emails and getting this NDR, you have either typed in the wrong email address or the email address doesn't exist on the server you are sending to.

If people are getting this message when they email your users, check the email address or alias exists on your email server. Also check if you have any address list filtering set up with a third party provider (such as MessageLabs) where you have to provide a list of all valid email addresses, and if somebody sends an email to a person not on this list, the message is bounced.

### Edit

The 5.7.1 message you are getting means you are not authorised to send email to the remote server (slight tangent - [this Microsoft KB article on SMTP status codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256321) is very useful, and definitely one to bookmark).

The reason you are getting a not authorised from the remote server could be several things. You could be on a blacklist, or the remote server might have other rules defined that are rejecting your message (intentionally or otherwise).

If it's just 1 domain you're having a problem with, at this point I'd be inclined to get in contact with them on the phone or on another email address if you're able to get through on that. Let them know you're having a problem sending them mail and ask for the message to be passed onto their IT department. There's a possibility you'll be ignored, but you might get lucky - it does happen.

Comment: thanks for your reply mate, however now they rejected my Google Mail test with the reason 554 554 5.7.1 Delivery not authorized, message refused -- . (reason: BombData: '<div>=A0</div> <div>=A0</div> <d') (state 18) .

Comment: @Albert Widjaja - please see my edit in response to the 5.7.1 error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could be right man, Possibly with their server.

i guess when the "mail.starrpartnersfairfield.com.au" went down for maintenance, the other email server got to restrictive SPAM filter.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\andrew>nslookup
Default Server: ns.domain.local
Address: 10.44.1.4

> set q=mx
> starrpartnersfairfield.com.au
Server: ns.domain.local
Address: 10.44.1.4

Non-authoritative answer:
starrpartnersfairfield.com.au MX preference = 50, mail exchanger = mx2.bne.server-mail.com
starrpartnersfairfield.com.au MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mail.starrpartnersfairfield.com.au
>
```

it is very strange sometimes when i rely to the email above it works but sometimes it doesn't i guess when the MX changed into the "mx2.bne.server-mail.com" it gets rejected by the aggressive spam filter.

but thanks for the advice.